# Como começar um range a partir do 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

Desejo que na parte do

> input("Coloque a nota do aluno " + str(notas) + ":" )

o computador pergunte "**Coloque a nota do aluno 1:** " e não começando do 0, como fazer isso com a função range?

Código abaixo.

```
Alunos = int((input("Digite quantos alunos você deseja cadastrar: ")))
quantidadeAlunos = (list(range(Alunos)))

for notas in quantidadeAlunos:
    input("Coloque a nota do aluno " + str(notas) + ":" )
```

Comment: Note que você não precisa coagir o `range` numa `list` para poder iterar. O `range` é um gerador (`yielder`), uma parada bacana que consegue tratar uma lista de 5 milhões de elementos (ou mais!, tem exemplos de geradores em Python que vão para o infinito) usando quase nada de memória

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só incrementar o contador:

```
alunos = int(input("Digite quantos alunos você deseja cadastrar: "))
notas = []

for i in range(1, alunos + 1):
    nota = input("Coloque a nota do aluno " + str(i) + ":" )
    notas.append(nota)
```

Comment: Cigano, você está perdendo/não considerando o último aluno. Lembre-se que o intervalo do `range` é aberto no `stop`

Comment: É verdade. Corrigido.

Comment: Algo em sua resposta ainda me cheira estranho... Tipo, você declara que `notas` é uma lista vazia na linha 3, então na linha 5 você diz que `notas` será usado para iterar no intervalo desejado, transformando seu valor em inteiro; daí, na linha 7 você pede que o valor lido seja apendado no final do agora inteiro `notas`, para então iterar novamente para o próximo elemento do `range` (linha 5) e _perder_ o valor recém apendado... Creio que você desejava iterar sobre outra variável que não `notas`, nem `nota`, confere? Creio que iterar em `aluno_atual` seja o suficiente, removendo as linhas 2 e 8

Comment: Não entendi nada.

Comment: Tem um terminal Python a mão? Imprime o valor de `notas` no começo e no final de cada iteração. Infelizmente, não tenho um na minha máquina e não vou abrir agora um no browser

Comment: Corrigido de novo. É 6a de noite e já estou na 3a cerveja.

Comment: Mano, é quase sábado e eu tenho de entregar dez telas de um protótipo para um trabalho da pós até domingo =/ Tá osso, num consigo me concentrar, daí venho pro SO me discontrair

Comment: Tô assim também. Escrevendo capítulo de curso até umas 2 da manhã no horário daqui. Tem muita resposta daqui que coloco no curso. Boa sorte pra nós.

Answer (score 5):

É só colocar `+1` após o `i` ou `notas` no seu caso.

A variável `quantidadeAlunos` não precisa existir, a variável `Alunos` já faz isso.

**Ficando assim:**

```
Alunos = int(input("Digite quantos alunos você deseja cadastrar: "))

for i in range(Alunos):
    notas = input("Coloque a nota do aluno " + str(i+1) + ":" )
```

Answer (score 4):

Existem 3 formas de se chamar o `range` em Python:

1. `range(INI, FIM, INC)`, essa é, digamos assim, a forma básica do `range` em Python. O intervalo começa com valor `INI`, sendo incrementado pelo valor `INC` a cada iteração até que chegue ou ultrapasse o valor de `FIM`; segue a fórmula a seguir, para `i` crescente começando do zero: [image: descrição matemática do conjunto]
2. `range(INI, FIM)`, neste caso, assume-se que o valor de incremento `INC` seja unitário;
3. `range(FIM)`; neste caso, assume-se que o início `INI` seja o 0 e que o incremento `INC` seja unitário.

Vale sempre ressaltar que o intervalo é fechado no começo (ou seja, inclui `INI`) e aberto no final (ou seja, não chega em `FIM`, para exatamente no passo anterior).

Tomando de posse deste conhecimento, use a melhor semântica para o seu problema. No seu caso em particular, creio que você deseje usar esses valores apenas para a interação com o usuário, não na lógica interna de seu programa. Se for este o caso, o ideal é fazer como a resposta do [Anthony Gabriel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204407/64969): apenas a exibição é tratado para informar **índices mais amigáveis ao usuário**, tornando o uso do índice interno mais **amigável para o código**.

#### UPDATE

Caso a iteração não favoreça em nada a lógica interna da iteração, a resposta do [Cigano Morrison Mendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204406/64969) é mais performática e direta ao ponto.

Devo admitir que eu sou tendencioso a começar laços por zero, então por puro preconceito perderia essa micro otimização.

Answer (score -4):

Exemplo mais enxuto...

```
>>> lista = [c for c in range(1, 11, 1)]
>>> print(lista)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Mais enxuto ainda: `lista = list(range(1, 11))` (o terceiro parâmetro, caso não seja informado, é `1`, então nem precisa passá-lo). Ou, se for **só** pra imprimir os números, nem precisa criar a lista: `print(*range(1, 11))`