# Erro de Sintaxe na lista

Tags: python

Eu estava fazendo o seguinte exercício : "Faça um programa que leia 4 notas , mostre as notas e a media na tela. "

Meu programa ficou assim :

```
lista = [ ]

i =  0

soma = 0


while(i < 3):

      nota = int(input("Digite a nota do aluno:")    
      lista.append(nota)    
      i = i + 1
      soma = soma + nota

media = soma/4               


print("As notas foram:", lista)

print("A media foi:", media)
```

Porém , ele está dando erro de sintaxe na lista (`lista.append(nota)`). Alguém sabe o porquê ?

Comment: Faltou fechar um `)` na linha anterior, referente à função `int`.

Comment: Que besteira , muito obrigado. Faltou colocar i < 4 tambem.

Comment: A explicação do @AndersonCarlosWoss, ficou um pouco obscura, IMO, na verdade faltou parenteses na própria linha do int, então...Troque a linha: `nota = int(input("Digite a nota do aluno:") ` por `nota = int(input("Digite a nota do aluno:"))`

Comment: Troquei e deu tudo certo. Obrigado !

Comment: @user158657 , fica menos propenso a erro se você trocar esse `while i < 3` por um `for i in range(4)`. Veja mais [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204411/64969)