# Resolver polinómio entre intervalo de dois valores

Tags: python

```
x = eval(input())
x = eval(input())
polinomio = 3*x**3- 5*x + 0.8
for x in range (x,x,0.5):
    print(polinomio)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Utilizador/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/fdrew.py", line 4, in 
>       for x in range (x,x,0.5):
>   TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Você realmente quer algo que varie entre `[x,x)` variando de `0.5`?

Comment: Veja aqui como se utiliza o `range`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204411/64969

Comment: Mas são dois valores diferentes. Por exemplo, se o programa ler os valores 2.4 e 4.6, deverá imprimir o valor desse
polinómio para os pontos (valores de x) seguintes: 2.4, 2.9, 3.4, 3.9 e 4.4.

Comment: intervalo que começam no extremo inferior e espaçados de 0.5

Comment: Você espera que o interpretador saiba qual é o primeiro `x` e qual o segundo `x`? Para ele é tudo `x`, então você perdeu toda e qualquer referência à primeira informação lida. Sem falar que o que você chama de `polinomio` não é um polinômio, mas um número real obtido através do cálculo de um polinômio para `x` valendo seu segundo valor

Comment: Pode me dar uma sugestão então pff como introduzir outro valor para x e resolver para esses valores espaçados entre 0.5?

Comment: Sou noviço em python e agradecia uma resposta ao meu erro ou sugestão? Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Vamos resolver seu problema, passo a passo.

Primeiramente, vamos ver o uso do `range`. Vamos olhar [a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) e... poxa vida, só aceita números inteiros! Essa função aceita até 3 parâmetros (cheque [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204411/64969) para detalhes mais mastigados). Como vamos proceder então?

Uma alternativa é proceder aritmeticamente. Se desejamos pegar os valores entre `m` e `M` saltando de `0.5` em `0.5` (sendo `i` o iterador), isso é idêntico à pegar os valores entre `2*m` e `2*M` saltando de `1` em `1`, iterando na variável `i_dobro` que pode facilmente ser transformada em `i = i_dobro/2`. Porém isso só funciona em Python 3 (para Python 2 é preciso dividir por `2.0`) e se `m` e `M` forem inteiros...

Então talvez possamos usar `while`? Comecemos de `m`, enquanto menor que `M`, incrementando `0.5` a cada passo... é, parece razoável.

Agora, que tal descobrirmos quem é `m` e `M` que eu tanto citei acima? Bem, `m` é a margem inferior do intervalo, enquanto que `M` é a margem superior. Como esses dados são lidos da entrada padrão, e não tem nenhuma restrição nem texto complementar a esse problema, só me resta crer que as duas entradas serão números possivelmente fora de ordem. Então leiamos `n1` para o primeiro número e `n2` para o segundo número. Para determinar `m` e `M` é assim:

```
(M, m) = (n1, n2) if n1 > n2 else (n2, n1)
```

Pronto, então de modo geral nossa iteração fica assim (vou manter a sua leitura por mais que eu discorde dela):

```
n1 = eval(input())
n2 = eval(input())

(M, m) = (n1, n2) if n1 > n2 else (n2, n1)

i = m
while i < M:
    # ação interessante da iteração 
    i += 0.5
```

Então, como fazer a ação interessante da iteração? O resultado desejado é a impressão da avaliação do polinômio perante o `i` passado. Vejo as seguintes opções:

- calcular diretamente no `print`
- definir uma função a priori e chamá-la alegremente
- criar um lambda e chamá-la ainda mais alegremente

Para a primeira opção, só é necessário mudar o trecho comentado:

```
print(3* i**3 -5*i + 0.8)
```

Para a segunda opção, antes de fazer as leituras devidas, defina a função assim:

```
def polinomio(x):
    return 3* x**3 -5*x + 0.8
```

Então chame dentro do `print`:

```
print(polinomio(i))
```

Para a alternativa com lambda, antes da iteração, crie a função lambda e atribua para a variável `polinomio`:

```
polinomio = (lambda x: 3* x**3 -5*x + 0.8)
```

E chame dentro do `print` como se fosse uma função tradicional:

```
print(polinomio(i))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta e paciência. Entendi tudo o que disse e percebi tudo mas fiz run ao programa e está me a dar este erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\fdrew.py", line 4, in <module>
    M, m = n1, n2 if n1 > n2 else n2, n1
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @RiceGum corrigindo...

Comment: Pelo visto me confiei demais na resolução de tuplas do Python... veja aqui algo similar funcionando: https://ideone.com/fVoCqz; aproveitei e corrigi a resposta adequadamente

Comment: Peço desculpa mas não entendi de todo. Deu valores logo fixos? Não podem ser fixos tem de ser os que eu introduzo. Fiz run ao que apresentou e o output foi: 1 2
3 5

Comment: Nem sequer introduzi valores

Comment: Exemplo foi da sintaxe utilizada para pegar o maior e o menor, não foi do seu programa como um todo. Não vou por aqui um exemplo do seu programa do começo ao fim pois é de minha intenção que você tenha o esforço para costurar, com as informações que eu dei, o programa a fim de que você tenha treino em Python e adquira expertise. Se for ver, é só referente à parte que havia dado erro de muitos valores para desempacotar. O erro não acontece mais, usando  o código da maneira correta

Comment: Acho que já percebi, irei postar como tenho o programa. Relativamente aos valores pedidos no enunciado está me a dar 1 valor a menos no inicio e um valor a mais no fim,