# Arquivos Python

Tags: python

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
x=[]
x=0.1

for i in range (101):
    x = 2.6868*x - 0.2462*x**3
```

Quero salvar meus dados 'x' para manipulá-lo em outro software, fiz o seguinte:

```
with open( 'saida.txt', 'w' ) as arq:
    for n in x:
        arq.write( str(n) + '\n' )
```

não sei se está correto, e também não sei em que pasta essa 'saida.txt' foi salva, como resolvo esse problema

Comment: Primeiro, vamos entender o problema, pois o código não fez muito sentido. Você tem duas variáveis chamadas `x`? O que exatamente você precisa fazer? Calcular `2.6868*x - 0.2462*x**3` para todos os valores de `x` de 0 a 100 e salvar os resultados em um arquivo?

Comment: Então, x=0.1 é um valor inicial, a partir desse valor calcula a função recursiva x = 2.6868*x - 0.2462*x**3

Comment: Certo, então ao final `x` possuirá um valor, que nesse caso, seria 0.31539. O que seria `x=[]` e o que exatamente você quer gravar no arquivo?

Comment: Para "iterar" com valores quebrados e avaliar o polinômio, usei uma solução nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248505/64969 ; a função `range` só aceita inteiros, então se você não fizer uma função de transformação `f:Z-->R` para obter o valor de `x` sobre o valor de um índice inteiro qualquer (o `i` do `for i in range`), então melhor usar um `while`

Comment: Aproveitando, como essa função recursiva funciona? Ela não me parece convergir

Comment: Eu quero criar uma lista de valores para a função 'x', o valor inicial é 0.1, e a partir desse valor, faço as iterações para conseguir a sequência de valores de 'x', seria uma sequência do tipo [0.1, 0.2684, 0.7164, ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do seu código, você quis criar um lista para salvar os resultados de uma função de 3º grau, certo?

Para fazer isso, você teria que usar o método append do objeto Lista. Porém, antes de tudo, teríamos que mudar um pouco o código:

```
x=[]
for i in range (101):
    x.append(2.6868*i - 0.2462*i**3)

arq = open('saida.txt','a')
for n in x:
    arq.write(str(n)+'\n')
arq.close()
```

Rodando este código, você obteria o seguinte resultado, caso printasse a list x:

```
[0.0, 2.4406, 3.404, 1.4129999999999994, -5.009600000000001, -17.341, -37.058400000000006, -65.63900000000001, -104.56, -155.29860000000002, -219.332, -298.1374, -393.192, -505.97299999999996, -637.9576000000001, -790.6229999999999, -965.4464, -1163.905, -1387.476, -1637.6366, -1915.8639999999998, -2223.6354, -2562.428, -2933.719, -3338.9856, -3779.705, -4257.3544, -4773.411, -5329.352, -5926.6546, -6566.795999999999, -7251.2534000000005, -7981.504, -8759.025, -9585.2936, -10461.787, -11389.9824, -12371.357, -13407.387999999999, -14499.552599999999, -15649.328, -16858.1914, -18127.62, -19459.091, -20854.0816, -22314.069, -23840.530400000003, -25434.943, -27098.784, -28833.5306, -30640.66, -32521.649400000002, -34477.975999999995, -36511.117, -38622.5496, -40813.751000000004, -43086.1984, -45441.369000000006, -47880.74, -50405.7886, -53017.992, -55718.8274, -58509.772000000004, -61392.303, -64367.897600000004, -67438.033, -70604.18639999999, -73867.835, -77230.456, -80693.5266, -84258.524, -87926.92540000001, -91700.208, -95579.849, -99567.3256, -103664.115, -107871.6944, -112191.541, -116625.132, -121173.9446, -125839.45599999999, -130623.1434, -135526.484, -140550.955, -145698.0336, -150969.19700000001, -156365.9224, -161889.687, -167541.968, -173324.2426, -179237.98799999998, -185284.6814, -191465.80000000002, -197782.821, -204237.22160000002, -210830.479, -217564.0704, -224439.473, -231458.164, -238621.6206, -245931.32]
```

O arquivo "saida.txt" estaria na pasta que você esta manipulando seu script.
 Para mais infos da função open, segue o [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).
Além disso, qual função do python você esta usando?

*******Refatorando: Adicionando uma lista y para armazenar o resultado de uma função de x que começa com o valor 0.1 e passa por um loop 100 vezes**

`x = 0.1
y=[]
for i in range(101):
      x = 2.6868*x - 0.2462*x**3
      print(x)
      y.append(x)`

Comment: Alex, ela [comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250257/arquivos-python#comment513298_250257) que o `x = 0.1` é um valor inicial e que o `for` é para fazer um cálculo recursivo, ou seja, o `i` do `for` não é utilizado; ele existe apenas para determinar que o loop rode 100 vezes. Ou seja, o cálculo que você fez no `for` estaria errado. Quanto o que é `x = []` ainda é incerto, pois ela não explicou na pergunta.

Comment: Entendi Anderson! Não havia visto o comentário dela sobre o x = 0.1 ser um valor inicial, porém faz todo sentido o lance o calculo recursivo para o for.  Pelo que a Priscila postou agora, teríamos que usar essa lista(x) para armazenar os valores.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Agora com a resposta da Priscila (sabendo que ela quer guardar o valor em uma lista), ficou mais fácil. E se mudássemos o nome da lista para y, acho que resolveria, certo? Pensei em apenas adicionar uma lista y:                             
`x = 0.1
y=[]

for i in range(101):
    x = 2.6868*x - 0.2462*x**3
    y.append(x)`                                                                                                               O que acha? Faz sentido agora?

Comment: Sim, mude o nome da lista, continue fazendo a atribuição do valor x sendo a operação matemática recursiva e depois adicione o valor de x na lista.

Comment: Bacana! Valeu! =]

Comment: Certo, é possível salvar os dados com todas as casas decimais, porque parece que está truncando